# Is it possible to reduce RSS output in Mailchimp for a single list user?

Tags: rss, mailchimp

In mailchimp is it possible to reduce the number of emails a user receives in your list based on RSS automation.  Any way to give the user the option to set RSS email frequency?

Answer (score 1):

Yes but your obliged to create a second (duplicate) campaign with, for example a weekly frequency, versus daily frequency.

You have then to create a "Frequency" group where you will put two options : "Daily" and "Weekly".

You'll have then to create convenient segments to allocate daily and weekly newsletter's subscribers.